# bundle install errors at pg (0.16.0) on OS X 10.9

Tags: ruby, postgresql, osx-mavericks, pg, metasploit

I am trying to install metasploit on OS X 10.9.  Everything i run bundle install, at the `installing pg (0.16.0)` it errors out

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin13/rbconfig.rb:212: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local in PATH, mode 040777
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Using rake (10.1.0) 
Using i18n (0.6.5) 
Using multi_json (1.0.4) 
Using activesupport (3.2.14) 
Using builder (3.0.4) 
Using activemodel (3.2.14) 
Using arel (3.0.2) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.37) 
Using activerecord (3.2.14) 
Using database_cleaner (1.1.1) 
Using diff-lcs (1.2.4) 
Using factory_girl (4.2.0) 
Using fivemat (1.2.1) 
Using json (1.8.0) 
Installing pg (0.16.0) 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin13/rbconfig.rb:212: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local in PATH, mode 040777
checking for pg_config... no
No pg_config... trying anyway. If building fails, please try again with
 --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
    --with-pg
    --without-pg
    --with-pg-config
    --without-pg-config
    --with-pg_config
    --without-pg_config
    --with-pg-dir
    --without-pg-dir
    --with-pg-include
    --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
    --with-pg-lib
    --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/


Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/pg-0.16.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/pg-0.16.0/ext/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing pg (0.16.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.16.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I have tried to install `pg -v '0.16.0'` with no luck and `pg --without=pg` and `pg -v '0.16.0' -- --with-pg-config=/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.3.1/bin/pg_config`

No luck to any of them.  Any suggestions?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

brew install postgres

or

gem install pg

Answer (score 1):

You may need to put `pg_config` on the `PATH`. You need to make sure PostgreSQL is available in `/usr/local/` directly (not just in the Homebrew `Cellar`) then:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
```

and make sure that running:

```
pg_config --version
```

emits something like:

```
$ pg_config --version
PostgreSQL 9.2.5
```

Comment: added the export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin and no luck.  I did get the correct version outputted for pg_config.

Comment: Same output as before?

Answer (score 1):

i solved the problem .. what you might have done while installing ruby gems was you forgot to install  the postgres sql on your mac ....  i was to doing the same while to run metasploit on my mac ... so what i did wrong was i did installed postgres sql but it ended up with a error and i did let it go ... so i figured it out at last that i am supposed to install postgres sql to make the pg 0.16 gem to make work

so what you have to do is

1. GOTO [POSTGRES OFFICIAL WEBSITE](http://www.postgresql.org)
   AND DOWNLOAD THE GUI PACKAGE FOR THE MAC IT IS AROUND OF 52.37 MB
2. INSTALL IT
3. RUN " BUNDLER INSTALL " IN YOUR TERMINAL
4. IF IT SHOWS UP AN ERROR LOGIN AS ROOT
5. THEN AGAIN TRY 
   AND HOPEFULLY IT WILL INSTALL

NOW I GUESS YOU MUST BE THINKING HOW TO LOG IN AS ROOT

SO HERE IS HOW TO DO THAT

1. GO TO PREFERENCES

2.USER & GROUPS

3.click on login option (its just above the + and - sign )

1. if that option is locked click on that golden lock click on it .. enter you user password .. and that option will unlock

5.now on the right side there will be a button i.e JOIN click on it

6.then on pop up click on open network directory utility

1. click again on that red lock if it is locked >> enter your password

8.click on edit >> enable root

1. create a password

and you are done

now log out

now you'll se two ballons (in case if you have single user account it can be more ) click on the last one type root as username  and you know the password as you created it

and again run that bundler install and you are done